# can we use textArea inside a textArea if not then how to write matrix of trigonometric functions

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6

How to use `textArea` inside a `textArea`  or can be another text editor to write some mathematics equations,matrix etc?[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should reconsider why you want to do this, because it is both technically impossible (TextArea is not a container) and bad UX. Maybe you can describe your problem as a UI issue on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: i'm designing a tool to write a math equation. so it need to write like daum equation editor

Comment: That's not much more descriptive. Maybe you can upload a basic drawing of what it should look like and what it should do?

Comment: i've add some description...

Comment: Thanks, I'm still a bit unclear which parts of your drawing are supposed to be editable.

Comment: every part user can edit here ...

Comment: Even the `sin` keyword? And the integral signs? Should the user be able to select other signs then? Is this supposed to always be the same formula or does it have to be more generic? Please be more descriptive.

Comment: yes user can edit any where... have ever used daum equation editor? u can add in chrome from google web store...

Comment: Aha, I get it now. That's fairly complex stuff. As far is I understand it, you'll have to define a custom component per type of equation which will hold all of the necessary TextAreas. These custom components should then be added to the stage dynamically as the user selects equations from the menu. Unless you have a more specific question I can't be more precise than this.

Comment: thanks,custom component design is right idea. but it's not clear how to add at stage...

Comment: Is this the sort of thing your looking for: http://www.fmath.info/. There is a free Flex version, but I'm sure there are licence restrictions

Comment: yes,licence restrictions is there.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you want to write and edit mathematical equations. [fMath](http://www.fmath.info/flex/download.jsp) would be the quickest route to getting up and running and save the headache of hand rolling your own.